# Spark Scala: Task Not serializable error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using IntelliJ Community Edition with Scala Plugin and spark libraries. I am still learning Spark and am using Scala Worksheet.

I have written the below code which removes punctuation marks in a String:

```
def removePunctuation(text: String): String = {
  val punctPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]".r
  punctPattern.replaceAllIn(text, "").toLowerCase
}
```

Then I read a text file and try to remove punctuation:

```
val myfile = sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/data.txt",4).map(removePunctuation)
```

This gives error as below, any help would be appreciated:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(/home/ubuntu/src/main/scala/Test.sc:294)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(/home/ubuntu/src/main/scala/Test.sc:284)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(/home/ubuntu/src/main/scala/Test.sc:104)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(/home/ubuntu/src/main/scala/Test.sc:2090)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(/home/ubuntu/src/main/scala/Test.sc:366)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(/home/ubuntu/src/main/scala/Test.sc:365)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(/home/ubuntu/src/main/scala/Test.sc:147)
>       at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(/home/ubuntu/src/main/scala/Test.sc:108)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: A$A21$A$A21
>   Serialization stack:
>       - object not serializable (class: A$A21$A$A21, value: A$A21$A$A21@62db3891)
>       - field (class: A$A21$A$A21$$anonfun$words$1, name: $outer, type: class A$A21$A$A21)
>       - object (class A$A21$A$A21$$anonfun$words$1, )
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
>       at A$A21$A$A21.words$lzycompute(Test.sc:27)
>       at A$A21$A$A21.words(Test.sc:27)
>       at A$A21$A$A21.get$$instance$$words(Test.sc:27)
>       at A$A21$.main(Test.sc:73)
>       at A$A21.main(Test.sc)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.MyWorksheetRunner.main(MyWorksheetRunner.java:22)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @TGaweda suggests, Spark's `SerializationDebugger` is very helpful for identifying "the serialization path leading from the given object to the problematic object." All the dollar signs before the "Serialization stack" in the stack trace indicate that the container object for your method is the problem.

While it is easiest to just slap `Serializable` on your container class, I prefer to take advantage of the fact Scala is a functional language and use your function as a first class citizen:

```
sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/data.txt",4).map { text =>
  val punctPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]".r
  punctPattern.replaceAllIn(text, "").toLowerCase
}
```

Or if you really want to keep things separate:

```
val removePunctuation: String => String = (text: String) => {
  val punctPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]".r
  punctPattern.replaceAllIn(text, "").toLowerCase
}
sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/data.txt",4).map(removePunctuation)
```

These options work of course since `Regex` [is serializable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.11/#scala.util.matching.Regex) as you should confirm.

On a secondary but very important  note, constructing a `Regex` is expensive, so factor it out of your transformations for the sake of performance--possibly with a [broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).

Comment: Can you elaborate your last comment please?

Comment: Hi, an insight pls: As part of a refresher I ran the issue in the question on Databricks COMMUNITY EDITION. Now, that is a non-clustered setup, but normally the Serialization Errors occur as per what I can see. But it did not. It's a 2.4.4 version - what to think? File too small? Driver approach? Why do other errors show?

Answer (score 12):

As T. Gaweda already pointed out, you're most likely defining your function in a class that's not serializable. Because it is a pure function, i.e. it doesn't depend on any context of the enclosing class, I suggest you put it into a companion object which should extend `Serializable`. This would be Scala's equivalent of a Java static method:

```
object Helper extends Serializable {
  def removePunctuation(text: String): String = {
    val punctPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]".r
    punctPattern.replaceAllIn(text, "").toLowerCase
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the stacktrace, there is:

> $outer, type: class A$A21$A$A21

It is a very good hint. Your lambda is serializable, but your class is not serializable.

When you make lambda expression, then this expression has reference to outer class. Outer class in your case is not serializable, i.e. is not implementing Serializable or one of fields is not an instance of Serializable

Comment: BTW. It's probably a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate.. ;) However I don't have time to search the best answer to mark question as a duplicate. If you find some good explanation, please ping me and mark question as a duplicate

Comment: @TGaweda: Thanks for the answer, but me being in the learning phase, didn't understand it at all. I searched for this issue before I posted. However, none of them explain in depth of what all this means and how to fix it. If you can suggest a possible resolution, then any person in future who get this error will only thank you

Comment: @sumitb That's why I posted this answer :)

Comment: I think I didn't post my question clearly. Let me again clarify, I am writing everything within a "Scala Worksheet". There is no question about outer object being serializable or not. If I create a scala object/class with a main method, write out exactly the same code, then it works fine. I am requesting to find out how to test this out in a worksheet. I will be happy to hear some suggestions.

Comment: @T.Gawęda Could you please explain how to read the serialization stack, specifically how you inferred something from the "$outer, type: class A$A21$A$A21" part of the serialization stack? Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912790/how-do-i-read-a-scala-serialization-stack-from-spark