# Cannot write/save data to Ignite directly from a Spark RDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, ignite

I try to write dataframe to ignite using jdbc ,

The Spark version is : 2.1

Ignite version:2.3

JDK:1.8

Scala:2.11.8

this is my code snippet:

```
def WriteToIgnite(hiveDF:DataFrame,targetTable:String):Unit = {

  val conn = DataSource.conn
  var psmt:PreparedStatement = null

  try {
    OperationIgniteUtil.deleteIgniteData(conn,targetTable)

    hiveDF.foreachPartition({
      partitionOfRecords => {
        partitionOfRecords.foreach(
          row => for ( i <- 0 until row.length ) {
            psmt = OperationIgniteUtil.getInsertStatement(conn, targetTable, hiveDF.schema)
            psmt.setObject(i+1, row.get(i))
            psmt.execute()
          }
        )
      }
    })

  }catch {
    case e: Exception =>  e.printStackTrace()
  } finally {
    conn.close
  }
}
```

and then I run on spark ,it print erro message:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
>           at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:924)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:923)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:923)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2305)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2305)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2305)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2304)
>           at com.pingan.pilot.ignite.common.OperationIgniteUtil$.WriteToIgnite(OperationIgniteUtil.scala:72)
>           at com.pingan.pilot.ignite.etl.HdfsToIgnite$.main(HdfsToIgnite.scala:36)
>           at com.pingan.pilot.ignite.etl.HdfsToIgnite.main(HdfsToIgnite.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc2.JdbcConnection Serialization stack:
>           - object not serializable (class: org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc2.JdbcConnection, value:
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc2.JdbcConnection@7ebc2975)
>           - field (class: com.pingan.pilot.ignite.common.OperationIgniteUtil$$anonfun$WriteToIgnite$1,
>   name: conn$1, type: interface java.sql.Connection)
>           - object (class com.pingan.pilot.ignite.common.OperationIgniteUtil$$anonfun$WriteToIgnite$1,
>   )
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
>           ... 27 more

Anyone konws I to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592742/spark-scala-task-not-serializable-error

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you cannot serialize the connection to Ignite `DataSource.conn`. The closure you provide to `forEachPartition` contains the connection as part of its scope which is why Spark cannot serialize it.

Fortunately, Ignite provides a custom implementation of RDD which allows you to save values to it. You will need to create an `IgniteContext` first, then retrieve Ignite's shared RDD which provide distributed access to Ignite to save the `Row` of your RDD:

```
val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sparkContext, () => new IgniteConfiguration())
...

// Retrieve Ignite's shared RDD
val igniteRdd = igniteContext.fromCache("partitioned")
igniteRDD.saveValues(hiveDF.toRDD)
```

More information are accessible from the [Apache Ignite documentation](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd#section-igniterdd).

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the Serializable interface.

```
object Test extends Serializable { 
  def WriteToIgnite(hiveDF:DataFrame,targetTable:String):Unit = {
   ???
  }
}
```

I hope it would resolve your problem.