# Task serialization error when using UDF in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

When I create UDF function as shown above, I get Task Serialization error. This error appears only when I run the code in the cluster deploy mode using `spark-submit`. However, it works well in spark-shell.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

def mfnURL(arr: WrappedArray[String]): String = {
  val filterArr = arr.filterNot(_ == null)
  if (filterArr.length == 0)
    return null
  else {
    filterArr.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1
  }
}

val mfnURLUDF = udf(mfnURL _)

def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("nodeId", "url", "typology")                                                     
val result = df.withColumn("count", count("url").over(windowSpec))
  .orderBy($"count".desc)                                                                                            
  .groupBy("nodeId","typology")                                                                                      
  .agg(
  first("url"),
  mfnURLUDF(collect_list("source_url")),
  min("minTimestamp"),
  max("maxTimestamp")
)
```

I tried to add `spark.udf.register("mfnURLUDF",mfnURLUDF)`, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Excellent posting. This helps? https://www.placeiq.com/2017/11/how-to-solve-non-serializable-errors-when-instantiating-objects-in-spark-udfs/

Comment: What is the exception are you getting? Could you please provide the full stack trace? Spark provides the reason for the serialization issues in the trace

Comment: Please don't return `null` in Scala. Please please please.

Comment: @erip: What is the correct way?

Comment: You can use `Option[T]`.

Comment: @erip: Instead of null? What will it return? I need to get null values.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357164/sparksql-how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-user-defined-function).

Comment: @erip: Do you mean that it should be this? `(filterArr.length == 0) match {
        case true => None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try to create udf this way:

```
val mfnURL = udf { arr: WrappedArray[String] =>
  val filterArr = arr.filterNot(_ == null)
  if (filterArr.length == 0)
    return null
  else {
    filterArr.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not an expert, but in absence of merenpath, I think the point is that def function is part of a class or object and that causes serializable issue, whereas val function does not. def is a method. @Markus

Comment: I am hoping he will respond. Here is a good link imho https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592742/spark-scala-task-not-serializable-error/43596624

Comment: This udf function creates seriazable class: Class org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction extends Object implements Serializable