# Spark function not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a class:

```
class DataLoader {

  def rdd2RddTransform(
    ss: SparkSession,
    inputRDD: RDD[GenericRecord]): RDD[GenericRecord] = {

    inputRDD.asInstanceOf[RDD[TrainingData]]
            .map(reformatTrainingData)
  }

  private def reformatTrainingData: TrainingData => ReFormatedData
               = (trainingData: TrainingData) => {func implement}

}
```

It worked very well but it threw an exception:
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` after I made a small change to the map of RDD:

```
inputRDD.asInstanceOf[RDD[TrainingData]].map(reformatTrainingData(_))
```

I thought the two functions should be same but it seems they are not. Why they are different?

Comment: I suspect this is down to the difference between a Function and a Method in Scala. Can you post the portion of the stack trace that contains the serialization debugging information, please? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592742/spark-scala-task-not-serializable-error?rq=1 for an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because methods and functions are not quite interchangeable in Scala.

Functions are standalone objects (i.e. instances of classes such as `Function1`, `Function2`, `Function3`...), but methods remain tied to their enclosing class. This can create problems in Spark if the enclosing class is not `Serializable` - when Spark tries to serialize the method, it fails to serialize the associated class instance.

Note that your `reformatTrainingData` is *a method that returns a function*

So when you call something like:

```
rdd.map(reformatTrainingData)
```

you are actually invoking the no-arg `reformatTrainingData` method and returning a standalone `Function1` instance that can be safely serialized. You could also write this as

```
private def reformatTrainingData(): TrainingData => ReFormatedData ...

rdd.map(reformatTrainingData())
```

to emphasize that there's a method call occurring.

When you change to `reformatTrainingData(_)` you are instead using a partially-applied method; when Spark tried to serialize this, it needs to pull in and serialize the enclosing `DataLoader` class, which is not marked as `Serializable`.

The same problem would occur if `reformatTrainingData` were a simple method of type `TrainingData => ReFormatedData`.

If you mark `DataLoader` as `extends Serializable`, then either version should work.

It would also be OK to make `reformatTrainingData` into a `val`, because vals don't pull in the enclosing class when serialized:

```
private val reformatTrainingData: TrainingData => ReFormatedData ...

rdd.map(reformatTrainingData)
```