# How do I read a Scala serialization stack (from Spark)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do I read a serialization stack?

I'm building a distributed NLP application on top of Spark. I periodically run into these NotSerializable exceptions, and always muddle my way through them. But, I've never found good documentation on what everything in the Serialization stack means.

How do I read a Serialization stack accompanying a NotSerializable error in Scala? How do I pinpoint the class or object that is causing the error? What is the significance of the 'field', 'object', 'writeObject' and 'writeReplace' fields in the stack?

An example is below:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: MyPackage.testing.PreprocessTest$$typecreator1$1
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: MyPackage.testing.PreprocessTest$$typecreator1$1, value: MyPackage.testing.PreprocessTest$$typecreator1$1@27f6854b)
        - writeObject data (class: scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag)
        - object (class scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag, scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag@4a571516)
        - writeReplace data (class: scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag)
        - object (class scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTagImpl, TypeTag[String])
        - field (class: MyPackage.package$$anonfun$deserializeMaps$1, name: evidence$1$1, type: interface scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag)
        - object (class MyPackage.package$$anonfun$deserializeMaps$1, <function1>)
        - field (class: MyPackage.package$$anonfun$deserializeMaps$1$$anonfun$apply$4, name: $outer, type: class MyPackage.package$$anonfun$deserializeMaps$1)
        - object (class MyPackage.package$$anonfun$deserializeMaps$1$$anonfun$apply$4, <function1>)
        - field (class: MyPackage.package$$anonfun$deserializeMaps$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5, name: $outer, type: class MyPackage.package$$anonfun$deserializeMaps$1$$anonfun$apply$4)
        - object (class MyPackage.package$$anonfun$deserializeMaps$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5, <function1>)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2, name: func$2, type: interface scala.Function1)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2, <function1>)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(UDF(tokenMap#149)))
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, UDF(UDF(tokenMap#149)) AS tokenMap#3131)
        - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
        - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(id#148, UDF(UDF(tokenMap#149)) AS tokenMap#3131, UDF(UDF(bigramMap#150)) AS bigramMap#3132, sentences#151, se_sentence_count#152, se_word_count#153, se_subjective_count#154, se_objective_count#155, se_document_sentiment#156, UDF(UDF(se_category#157)) AS se_category#3133))
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project, name: projectList, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project, Project [id#148,UDF(UDF(tokenMap#149)) AS tokenMap#3131,UDF(UDF(bigramMap#150)) AS bigramMap#3132,sentences#151,se_sentence_count#152,se_word_count#153,se_subjective_count#154,se_objective_count#155,se_document_sentiment#156,UDF(UDF(se_category#157)) AS se_category#3133]
+- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [se_sentence_count#152,bigramMap#150,id#148,tokenMap#149,se_word_count#153,sentences#151,se_document_sentiment#156,se_subjective_count#154,se_category#157,se_objective_count#155], InMemoryRelation [id#148,tokenMap#149,bigramMap#150,sentences#151,se_sentence_count#152,se_word_count#153,se_subjective_count#154,se_objective_count#155,se_document_sentiment#156,se_category#157], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), Union, None
)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ConvertToSafe, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ConvertToSafe, ConvertToSafe
+- Project [id#148,UDF(UDF(tokenMap#149)) AS tokenMap#3131,UDF(UDF(bigramMap#150)) AS bigramMap#3132,sentences#151,se_sentence_count#152,se_word_count#153,se_subjective_count#154,se_objective_count#155,se_document_sentiment#156,UDF(UDF(se_category#157)) AS se_category#3133]
   +- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [se_sentence_count#152,bigramMap#150,id#148,tokenMap#149,se_word_count#153,sentences#151,se_document_sentiment#156,se_subjective_count#154,se_category#157,se_objective_count#155], InMemoryRelation [id#148,tokenMap#149,bigramMap#150,sentences#151,se_sentence_count#152,se_word_count#153,se_subjective_count#154,se_objective_count#155,se_document_sentiment#156,se_category#157], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), Union, None
)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ConvertToSafe$$anonfun$2, name: $outer, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ConvertToSafe)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ConvertToSafe$$anonfun$2, <function1>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a feeling of what that output means when looking at `SerializationDebugger.scala`'s [visit](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0fd1f85f16502d1d4222cf3d7abfd5e2b86464e6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/serializer/SerializationDebugger.scala#L84) method.

At the time of writing this comment, it looks like this:

```
    /**
     * Visit the object and its fields and stop when we find an object that is not serializable.
     * Return the path as a list. If everything can be serialized, return an empty list.
     */
    def visit(o: Any, stack: List[String]): List[String] = {
      if (o == null) {
        List.empty
      } else if (visited.contains(o)) {
        List.empty
      } else {
        visited += o
        o match {
          // Primitive value, string, and primitive arrays are always serializable
          case _ if o.getClass.isPrimitive => List.empty
          case _: String => List.empty
          case _ if o.getClass.isArray && o.getClass.getComponentType.isPrimitive => List.empty

          // Traverse non primitive array.
          case a: Array[_] if o.getClass.isArray && !o.getClass.getComponentType.isPrimitive =>
            val elem = s"array (class ${a.getClass.getName}, size ${a.length})"
            visitArray(o.asInstanceOf[Array[_]], elem :: stack)

          case e: java.io.Externalizable =>
            val elem = s"externalizable object (class ${e.getClass.getName}, $e)"
            visitExternalizable(e, elem :: stack)

          case s: Object with java.io.Serializable =>
            val elem = s"object (class ${s.getClass.getName}, $s)"
            visitSerializable(s, elem :: stack)

          case _ =>
            // Found an object that is not serializable!
            s"object not serializable (class: ${o.getClass.getName}, value: $o)" :: stack
        }
      }
    }
```

So this `visit` method traverses your object that needs to be serialized. There are multiple cases:

There are cases where there is no serialization issue:

- your object is `null`
- `visited.contains(o)` => you've traversed the whole object without an issue
- `o.getClass.isPrimitive` => you're serializing a primitive type
- `String` can be serialized
- `o.getClass.isArray && o.getClass.getComponentType.isPrimitive` => serializing an array of primitive types

Then there are 3 cases, where a more complicated object is encountered and it needs to be checked whether that complicated object contains unserializable objects. They call the `visitArray`, `visitExternalizable` and `visitSerializable` functions on the serialization stack with the current element popped off (see `elem :: stack`) and they end up calling `visit` again. This happens recursively until:

- you're done traversing the object (`visited.contains(o)`)
- you bounce onto an unserializable object

In your case, it seems like you made a UDF that needed to be serialized. It contained a bunch of `Serializable` objects (ConvertToSafe, Project, List, Alias, ScalaUDF, some anonymous functions, TypeTags) and then finally bounced against the unserializable object: `MyPackage.testing.PreprocessTest`. So that last one is the one you need to make serializable if you want this to pass.

Hope this helps!